# Vue Reactivity problem when update a property value in an object

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, frontend, reactive

I have this chatRoom application which receives the messages through a socket connection. The message structure is a single object which saves messages in a chatRoom array inside the object.

[image: Vue dev tool capture]

Problem is when messages received it's not reactively rendered into the view. I have to re-render the component to take the updated messages 
The Message variable is in the component data. Vuex is not attached.

I have tried with Vue.set to set the incoming messages to the variable

This is the function triggered by the socket onMessage is recieved.

```
   addMessage(message){
      var chatMessage = JSON.parse(message.data)
      console.log(chatMessage)
      if(Boolean(this.messages[chatMessage.chatRoomId])){
        var allMessages = this.messages[chatMessage.chatRoomId];
        allMessages.push(chatMessage)
        Vue.set(this.messages, chatMessage.chatRoomId, allMessages)
      }
    },
```

This is the place where render happens.

```
<li
      class="message"
      v-for="(message, index) in messages[activeChatRoom]"
      v-bind:key="message.id"
      v-bind:index="index"
      v-bind:title="message.msg"
>{{ message.message }}
</li>
```

The active chatRoom is changed by a click event.

Any help on this is appreciated

Comment: is the this.messages a data property? If so, there is no reason to use vue.set. Vue.set adds a property  the reactive set to be picked up for re-renders. If you are just adding a message to a list of messages why are you not doing this.messages.push(newmessage) ?

Comment: Thank for the comment. I also tried that. But not render to the view. In dev tools, it shows that messages are stored. But not render to the view. So I just try this. But nothing happens :/

Comment: Wait so are you storing these in Vuex? you are not providing enough information about your data.

Comment: Sorry. I will edit the question. Vuex is not linked. Just a single component with data

Comment: Nested one level too deep to work.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: You mentioned that `messages` is declared in `data` but when do you add in the chatroom arrays? Are they there initially or do you add those subsequently? Everything you've posted makes me think that those arrays aren't themselves reactive due to property addition. So `allMessages.push(chatMessage)` is pushing to a non-reactive array and the `Vue.set` call on the following line won't help as `Vue.set` only adds reactivity if the property doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 0):

[vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#Vue-set)

Vue.set's second parameter must be string or number,So only the target of the set can only be nested one level in my opinion.So i change the first parameter,and it worked....

I don't know the deeper reason, you can go and see Vue.set source code.

ps:Watch, vuex,and $nextick should also be able to implement monitoring data

a single domo:

```
    <template>
  <div class="hello">
    <p>{{msg.title.text}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'problem',
  data(){
    return {
      msg:{
        title:{
          text:'test'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.$set(this.msg.title,'text','haha')
      console.dir(this.msg)
    },2000)
  }
}
</script>
```